# Java: Synchronize an ExecutorService necessary?

Tags: java, synchronization, executorservice

I have a class containing an ExecutorService that can be shared between threads:

```
class MyExecutor {
    ExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ....
    .... 
    public void add(Runnable r) {
         e.executre(r);
    } 
}
```

Is it necessary to synchronize the ExecutorService object in the `add` method since the `add` method can be called from differens threads or is the ExecutorService thread safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702386/is-threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ExecutorService has to use a thread safe queue (Which it does by default). This is all that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no need to synchronize calls to add() method.