# ServletContextListener: Isn't this incorrect usage?

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0

I was going through a expert(?) tutorial on "Asynchronous processing support in Servlet 3.0" (http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=2). In it there is this following code snippet:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet", urlPatterns={"/slowprocess"}, asyncSupported=true)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        AsyncContext aCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);
        ServletContext appScope = request.getServletContext();
        ((Queue<AsyncContext>)appScope.getAttribute("slowWebServiceJobQueue")).add(aCtx);
    }
}

@WebServletContextListener
public class SlowWebService implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Queue<AsyncContext> jobQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<AsyncContext>();
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("slowWebServiceJobQueue", jobQueue);
        // pool size matching Web services capacity
        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        while(true)
        {
            if(!jobQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                final AsyncContext aCtx = jobQueue.poll();
                executor.execute(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        ServletRequest request = aCtx.getRequest();
                        // get parameteres
                        // invoke a Web service endpoint
                        // set results
                        aCtx.forward("/result.jsp");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
```

}

Since, this was an expert 'this-is-how-it-is-done' article I am assuming that they wouldnt be writing some silly code.
But I am unable to accept having a 'while(true)' loop inside 'contextInitialized()'.

1. As per my understanding, this context listener thread would never exit the 'contextInitialized()' method. Right ?
2. What happens to any other Servlets I have in my application ? Are they free to service requests ? Or does this bring down the entire servlet container ?

Comment: This code does not clean up on contextDestroyed and it will not stop running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I would change the code as following:

```
@WebServletContextListener
public class SlowWebService implements ServletContextListener, Runnable {
    private volatile boolean running;
    ExecutorService executor;
    Thread runner;
    Queue<AsyncContext> jobQueue;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        jobQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<AsyncContext>();
        sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("slowWebServiceJobQueue", jobQueue);
        // pool size matching Web services capacity
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while(running)
        {
            try {
                if(!jobQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    final AsyncContext aCtx = jobQueue.poll();
                    executor.execute(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            ServletRequest request = aCtx.getRequest();
                            // get parameteres
                            // invoke a Web service endpoint
                            // set results
                            aCtx.forward("/result.jsp");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        running = false;
        runner.interrupt();
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

2) Other Servlets shouldn't be affected as long as they have a different urlPattern.

Comment: 'executor' is accessed by both 'runner' thread and the 'context-listener-event-handling' thread. Should it not be volatile or synchronized in some way ?

Comment: I suppose the reason for setting 'running' to false AND 'interrupt'ing the thread, is to force the thread out of its 'poll' and get it to look at whether it should be 'running' any more. Right ?

Comment: @vendhan yes that is right, otherwise the thread will not stop when the context is destroyed. And you don't need to synchronize executor in this context.

Comment: Agreed that the executor need not be synchronized, after referring [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702386/is-threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe?lq=1) But its unbelievable that this is not properly documented in the spec !

Comment: Can you pls answer question#2 ? So that I can select this as the answer.

Comment: @vendhan added answer for part 2