# Java ExecutorService: should I put a lock before to use execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class organized as follows:

```
public class MyClass {

   ExecutorService pool;

   public MyClass(){
     pool = ... //inited by a class that implements ExecutorService
   }

   public final void submit(Runnable run){
        pool.execute(run);
   }
}
```

Is the method `submit` thread safe or I should use a `Lock`-based system? E.g.

```
   ReentrantLock look  = new ReentrantLock();

   public final void submit(Runnable run){
        lock.lock();
        try{ pool.execute(run); } finally{lock.unlock();}
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you don't need the lock when calling [ExecutorService#submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task, which in turn happen-before the result is retrieved via Future.get().

or when calling [Executor#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is complete and exhaustive!

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your `ExecutorService` is accessed or how your `MyClass` is created. If an instance of `MyClass` is created in a single thread and the `#pool` ivar is also created in a single thread then this class is thread-safe and your use of `#pool` is threadsafe.

However, if your `MyClass` can exist across multiple threads (such as first accessed through a singleton, shared factory or shared list - i.e. not `new MyClass()`) then it is not thread-safe. This is because multiple threads could access your `Myclass` instance and its single `#pool` ivar. Calling submit could be done but multiple threads at once and so the state of your `Myclass` instance or `pool` could be compromised. In this case, your `MyClass#submit` should be synchronised or managed by locks. As it's a petite method, I'd suggest just synchronising `#submit`.

Likewise, if your `MyClass` instance is created in this thread but `#pool` is not created as new in this thread (`pool = new AnExecutorPoolType(...);` then this class would again not be threadsafe. The pool may again be accessed from another source(as above) that is available across multiple threads. If that's the case then there is a risk of it being left in an inconsistent state by multiple thread accesses. In this case, the `pool#execute` method should be synchronised (or through a synchronised block guarding ivar access) or managed through locks.

Comment: Actually, MyClass is an enum designed for use the pool as a singleton.

Comment: I've re-read my answer here with some alarm, thinking 'doesn't look right'. However, I'm going to leave it as the point I think I'm making is... ExecutorService may be threadsafe (though that really depends on the implementation [though java impls are "happens-before"] ), but your implementation of submit may not be thread-safe. It's plausible that a different thread could come in within your `Myclass#submit` and cause the order to be not as you would expect - before reaching the `ExecutorService`. So, your class may need to guard against this.

Comment: See also [Is ThreadPoolExecutor thread safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702386/is-threadpoolexecutor-thread-safe).