# Is volatile enough in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is my app's start/stop procedure, start/stop code is handled by a single-threaded `ThreadPoolExecutor`, so I'm guaranteed there's only one thread can be active at the same time.

I'm asking about `isRunning` variable. Is making the variable `volatile` enough?
The variable will be accessed (read/modify) from different threads (but only one at the same time!)

EDIT:
Added variable reading (beginning of `startProcedure()` and `stopProcedure()`). I forgot about that part, my apologies.

EDIT2:
I think it may be hard to notice, but `startProcedure()` and `stopProcedure()` are functions used to create `startQuery` and `stopQuery` - Runnables used by threads.

```
public final class Work {

    private static final ThreadPoolExecutor processor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
    private static final Runnable startQuery = Work::startProcedure,
            stopQuery = Work::stopProcedure;

    private static boolean isRunning = false;

    private Work() {}

    private static void startProcedure() {
        if (isRunning) return;
        isRunning = true;
        //<some code>
    }

    private static void stopProcedure() {
        if (!isRunning) return;
        //<some code>
        isRunning = false;
    }

    //------Public API

    public static void start() {
        processor.execute(startQuery);
    }

    public static void stop() {
        processor.execute(stopQuery);
    }

}
```

Comment: You example only shows assignments to the isRunning variable. If there isn't any code that _examines_ the variable, then it doesn't matter how you declare it. If there is code that you haven't _shown_ in your example, then it's going to be pretty hard for anybody to comment on it in any meaningful way.

Comment: @SolomonSlow You're right, I forgot to add the variable reading part. Just added it at the beginning of `startProcedure()` and `stopProcedure()`

Comment: @WLTY He is asking about how threads access this variable, not some trivial reads inside the setters. How is `isRunning` used in the tasks?

Comment: @akuzminykh read the code once again, `startProcedure()` and `stopProcedure()` are being used by the threads, there's no other code the threads perform

Comment: @WLTY As you don't show any functionality and this is all we have, then I say yes: `volatile` is enough. I'm assuming that you are only asking about visibility and nothing else.

Comment: @akuzminykh I think you're starting to understand me :) My question is: Is volatile enough to make isRunning visible to any next performing thread?

Comment: @WLTY Of course, that's the point of `volatile`.

Comment: @WLTY However, just to point it out, `volatile` is enough in *any* case when it's about visibility *only*. If your code breaks because of wrong synchronization, that's a different story.

Comment: If only one thread runs at a time, there's no point of talking about thread safety. After all it's a sequential execution.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala volatile isn't about thread safety anyway

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `volatile` has very little to do with "thread-safety". `volatile` is about *visibility* and the guarantees it offers around that; specifically it works around "happens-before" principle (I will not dive into this, though).

Your case is a little bit interesting: you have a single thread. So the real question is, are actions that are done as part of the `start` method *visible* to the next *stop* method? In other words does `ThreadPoolExecutor::execute` offer any visibility guarantees?

It seems to me the answer is: yes and you do not need volatile at all. The `ExecutorService`, that `ThreadPoolExecutor` implements says:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a Runnable or Callable task to an ExecutorService happen-before any actions taken by that task...

The way I interpret this is: actions that are done in the *start* thread will happen-before actions that are done in the *stop* thread. But this guarantee can only be made if `start` and `stop` are called (and wait) one after another - like in your example. As soon as you change the inner implementation, this will not work.

Comment: You may be right, but on the other hand the quoted part may mean that **submission** of the Runnable will be visible, so `ExecutorService.submit()` can be used safely across multiple threads. Here's more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058419/java-executorservice-should-i-put-a-lock-before-to-use-execute

Answer (score 0):

Yes `volatile` keyword is good enough for your use case.

> The Java `volatile` keyword is used to mark a Java variable as **being stored in main memory**. More precisely that means, that every read of a volatile variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the CPU cache, and that every write to a volatile variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the CPU cache.

Comment: there is no such thing as "main memory". and if you quote something - might include where this quote comes from. and a simple "yes" is no answer either

Comment: Do correct and enlighten me with your understanding and share how I am wrong.

Comment: Volatile doesn't mean every read will happen from the computer's main memory. This is a common misconception. If volatiles were read/written from main memory every time, the performance impact would be very underwhelming. The actual cost depends on the CPU architecture which, in a broader context, using protocols such as the MESI, shares a **coherent cache line** ("spying other caches") enforcing that when two threads read from the same memory address, they should never simultaneously read different values. https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/